ServiceNow Create Attachment via File or Upload via Rest API?
As per the ServiceNow Documentation, there are two ways we can upload a file to ServiceNow via Rest Api :
https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/xanadu/rest/c_AttachmentAPI#attachment-POST-file
Currently following the api/now/attachment/file which Uploads a specified binary file as an attachment to a specified record.
Note: The file to attach must be specified after the last parameter in the passed-in request parameter list.
How to set the binary file in the below code so that it can use the existing generic method CreateRecord to upload it thereafter
private async Task UploadAttachment(CRMContext crmContext, ServiceNowAttachment attachment, ServiceNowQueryOptions requestOptions)
 {
     if (attachment.FileData != null && attachment.FileData.Length > 0)
     {
         using var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(attachment.FileData);
         fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"); // Adjust MIME type if needed
         content.Add(fileContent, "file", attachment.FileName!);
     }  --how to send the content? 

     JObject? additionalFields = null; // not used for CreateAttachment

     // Create the record using CreateRecord
     await this.serviceNowClient.CreateRecord<ServiceNowAttachment>(
         crmRequestContext,
         attachment,
         additionalFields, // No additional fields for attachment
         requestOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
 }

How will it get uploaded like this? As per the constraints , CreateRecord params can't be changed, so we need to send the attachment / file like this only

It's done after mapping the FileData of FileAttachment to the mapped model and pass it like ByteArrayContent
ServiceNowQueryOptions queryOptions = new ServiceNowQueryOptions()
{
    BaseUrl = $"{ServiceNowFileAttachmentHttpRequest}",
    FileContent = new ByteArrayContent(snFileAttachment.FileData!),
};
queryOptions.FileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(snFileAttachment.ContentType!);
JObject? additionalFields = null; // not used for CreateAttachment
await this.serviceNowClient.CreateRecord<ServiceNowAttachment>(context, snFileAttachment, additionalFields, queryOptions!).ConfigureAwait(false);

